# makefile loop var pipe

Tags: loops, command-line, makefile

I'm trying to do a loop in a make to exec a remote ssh command to optain the pid of a process to kill it.
Like this:

```
target:
  for node in 23 ; do \
    echo $$node ; \
    ssh user@pc$$node "~/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/jps | grep CassandraDaemon | awk  '{print \$$1}'" > $(PID); \
    ssh user@pc$$node "kill -9 $(PID); \
  done
```

But I get:

```
/bin/sh: 3: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
```

The issue I think is to store the pid that the remote ssh command returns (it woks well without the `> $(PID)` )

Comment: You seem to have an unmatched doublequote on the second last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` redirects into files, not into variables.  `$()` captures in a way you can assign to variables... but is also `make` syntax, so you need to escape it.  You also need to escape it when you use it so that you don't get the `make` variable instead (no, you can't store it in a `make` variable).

```
for node in 23 ; do \
    echo $$node ; \
    PID=$$(ssh user@pc$$node "~/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/jps | grep CassandraDaemon | awk  '{print \$$1}'"); \
    ssh user@pc$$node "kill -9 $$PID; \
done
```

(assuming one of your many, many edits hasn't changed things too much from when I copied and pasted that to fix it...)

Comment: Thanks geekosaur!!!!
Only to say that the correct final line is:
ssh user@pc$$node "kill -9 $$PID"; \
The last "